# Preventing ASP.NET MVC 4 from redirecting when authentication required

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to avoid redirecting.

I added this code to the global.asax

```
protected void Application_EndRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpApplication context = (HttpApplication)sender;
    context.Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
}
```

It is not working. When I debug I see that the code is executed, but it keeps redriceting.

For the request of anuj.rohila94, I share the whole global.asax:

```
namespace AngularJSMVC
{
    // Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
    // visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801

    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
        }

        protected void Application_EndRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            HttpApplication context = (HttpApplication)sender;
            context.Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happen if you put this code in Application_BeginRequest ?

Comment: Please see the comments for the accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18519446/prevent-asp-net-from-redirecting-to-login-aspx/18519725#18519725

Answer (score 0):

I think this is perfect code this will not keeps redirecting application.

May be other code is affect your redirection.

provide your Global file all methods.

Comment: I updated the post with the whole global.asax.cs, do you see anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please use custom authentication attribute for your implementation.Attaching few links for your references as I am not aware about your implementation of Authorization.

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=957

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/650240/A-Simple-Action-Filter-Overview

Please let us know if you have any questions on this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked the installed version of .net framework and your targeted version of .net framework. Sometimes it can occur due to conflict on versions.

Comment: My targeted framwork is 4.5. Before that the SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect is not available. And I think that if the 4.5 were not installed the application would not run.