# Redirect user to custom access denied page

Tags: asp.net, web-config, access-denied

I have in my web.config file within each directory some access settings for each page in the directory like so.

```
  <location path="orderForm.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="AdmStf" />
        <allow roles="OrdPage" />

        <deny users="*,?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

This works perfectly well. But, when the user does not have the correct level of access, the user is directed automatically it seems to the Default.aspx page in the root directory.

What i would like to do, is actually send the user to a custom AccessDenied.aspx page.

in my main web.config file I have the following...

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Views/Err/Error.aspx">
  <error statusCode="401" redirect="~/Views/Err/AccessDenied.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

But this is not working as I expected it to. The user is still directed to the Default.aspx page.

Is there a way to achieve what I want here?

Comment: Do not redirect users in error conditions - instead the serve the error response with the 401 response header, otherwise the browser or other UAs won't recognize that the response really is an error.

Comment: everything i read on the internet seems to point to doing it this way, so i'm not sure why this doesn't work, it's usually marked as the answer to the problem...

Answer (score 1):

You can check this ([customerrors for 401.2 in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057014/customerrors-for-401-2-in-asp-net))

As a workaround, you can handle it in Authenication_Request event in Global.asax and redirect the unauthorized users

However, my recommendation is to redirect unauthorized requests to log in page. as the requester may be authorized but just forgot to log in. So your approach will add extra step.